# ASP.Net simple membership login with email or username

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, extend, simplemembership

In my app I want to enable login with email or username. I found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404438/how-to-make-websecurity-login-to-login-using-username-or-email) , which is extending the simpleMembershiProvider. In this solution there is stated, that I have to register this new membership provider in web.config file but I am unable to find any guide how to do it, so I would be thankful for any instructions how to register the extended provider or for any other solution how to enable login with email or username.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your web.config under System.Web and tweak the settings in that configuration to match your requirements.

```
<membership defaultProvider="AccountMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AccountMembershipProvider" type="Yourcustomclasswithnamespace" connectionStringName="yourdatabaseconnectionstringname" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="yourappname"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer unfortunetely I am getting error: "This method cannot be called during the application's pre-start initialization phase." on line <add name="AccountMembershipProvider" type="FM.Membership.ExtendedMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="MyDBContext"... can you help me on this one please?

Comment: Ok I guess I find an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626647/asp-net-this-method-cannot-be-called-during-the-applications-pre-start-initial